# P channel MOSFET unexpected current leakage

Tags: mosfet, high-current, pmos, leakage-current

I am using a P-channel MOSFET to drive a load. My load is an bluetooth module consuming 6 uA (according to datasheet) in sleep mode. I am controlling the gate with the main MCU which is stm32l4.

The problem is as follows:

1. While drinvg bluetooth module with the MOSFET, I observe the current of 70 uA (ampermeter between VCC and MOSFET source)
2. When I remove the MOSFET and capacitor from the circuit and short circuit the drain and source of the mosfet pads, I measured 6 uA (ampermeter between VCC and MOSFET source pad). 
   According to the [mosfets document](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMP3099L.pdf), gate source leakage current is only 100 nA. My GPIO configuration is push pull output. After the mosfet Cgs capacitance has charged there should be no current flow.

What can be the reason of current increase?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpe8cK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: where do you call "mosfet drain" ? It does not seem meaningful to me to connect the ampermeter between Vcc and drain.

Comment: sorry, I edited my post. I meant source not drain.

Comment: Can you measure the voltage between the gate and the source?

Comment: when mosfet is not conducting Vgs = 0V , when it is conducting Vgs = -3.0081V(which is Vcc)

Comment: If I understand correctly, your system consume more current with the MOSFET rather than without (70µA vs 6µA). I think the Rdson of the MOSFET is high and consuming current. Can you measure the Vds voltage?

Comment: yes, that's correct. I am trying to solve it. I measured Vds and it's 12uV

Comment: Did you build this yourself? If so... might be ESD damage?

Comment: I have 2 samples, the measurements are same for both. I made the assembly myself.